# Why is my Blade template content displayed twice?

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm having trouble with my blade templates.  For some reason, I get the content of my view printed out twice, once by the `yield` where I would expect but also another time before the view that is extended performs any action.

My route is:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function () {
    return View::make('default');
}));
```

The default view (`default.blade.php`) is this:

```
@extends('test')

@section('title')
    Default
@show

@section('content')
    <p>Content goes here<p>
@show
```

And the test view (`test.blade.php`) is this:

```
<h1>Anything above should be be there!</h1>
<h3>@yield('title')</h3>
@yield('content')
```

And this generates:

```
Default
<p>Content goes here<p>
<h1>Anything above should be be there!</h1>
<h3>Default</h3>
<p>Content goes here<p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
@extends('test')

@section('title')
    Default
@stop

@section('content')
    <p>Content goes here<p>
@stop
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch the difference between show and stop. Thanks!

Comment: Care to explain the difference between 'show' and 'stop'?

Comment: If you use `@show`, Laravel assumes this is your default value, which can be overriden by another `@section('content')`.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt this be...`@stop` instead of `@show`

```
@extends('test')

@section('title')
Default
@stop

@section('content')
<p>Content goes here<p>
@stop
```